# Xamarin.Forms - DisplayAlert with Italic font attribute

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup, italic

I need to display an alert with some part of the message in italics and the other part normal, something like this:

```
var title = "Title";
var body = "This part in Italic. This part normal.";
Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert(title, body, "OK");
```

With the part that says: "This part in Italic." in italics and the other one in normal text.

Is it possible to do? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As an alternative for 'DisplayAlert' you may want to use a custom pop up control instead. Take a look @ this: https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a native alert controller like this:

```
void PromptRichTextPopup(string title, string richMessage, string normalMessage, Action onOkCallback, Action onCancel = null) {
            var vc = UIKit.UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            // take top presented view controller
            while (vc.PresentedViewController != null) {
                vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
            }

            var alertvc = UIAlertController.Create(title, string.Empty, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            var leftAligned = new NSMutableParagraphStyle();
            leftAligned.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Left;

            var colorTitle = new NSAttributedString(str: title, font: UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(18), foregroundColor: Xamarin.Forms.Color.FromHex("#61acad").ToUIColor());

            alertvc.SetValueForKey(colorTitle, new NSString("attributedTitle"));

            var margin = 5f;
            var height = 30f;
            var width = 256f;

            var container = new UIView(new CGRect(margin, margin, width, height * 4));

            var message = new NSMutableAttributedString(str: richMessage, font: UIFont.ItalicSystemFontOfSize(14), foregroundColor: UIColor.Black);
            message.Append(new NSMutableAttributedString(str: " " + normalMessage, font: UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(14), foregroundColor: UIColor.Black));
            var lblText = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, -(height / 2), width, height * 2)) { AttributedText = message };
            lblText.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap;
            lblText.Lines = 0;
            container.AddSubview(lblText);

            var cancel = new UIButton(new CGRect(0, height, width / 2, height * 2));
            cancel.SetTitle("NO", UIControlState.Normal);
            cancel.AddTarget((sender, e) => alertvc.DismissViewController(true, null), UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
            cancel.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
            if (onCancel != null) {
                cancel.AddTarget((sender, e) => {
                    onCancel();
                },
                UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
            }
            container.AddSubview(cancel);

            var ok = new UIButton(new CGRect(width / 2, height, width / 2, height * 2));
            ok.SetTitle("YES", UIControlState.Normal);
            Action okAction = async () => {
                ok.Enabled = false;
                await uiHelper.RunBlocking(() => {
                    onOkCallback();
                });
                alertvc.DismissViewController(true, null);
            };
            ok.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);
            container.AddSubview(ok);
            ok.AddTarget((sender, e) => {
                okAction();
            }, UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);

            var controller = new UIViewController();
            controller.View.AddSubview(container);
            alertvc.SetValueForKey(controller, new NSString("contentViewController"));
            vc.PresentViewController(alertvc, true, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use Custom Renderer to achieve (use a custom View and a renderer for handling a popup) it but [it is not recommended by iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/views/alerts/)

> Alerts convey important information related to the state of
>   your app or the device, and often request feedback. An alert consists
>   of a title, an optional message, one or more buttons, and optional
>   text fields for gathering input. Aside from these configurable
>   elements, the visual appearance of an alert is static and can’t be
>   customized.

[This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63143/displayalert-displayactionsheet-and-custom-renderer-question) may be helpful for you.